# How can I find context path in normal Java class

Tags: java, path

I want to find context path of my web Application in normal Java class.If I find I can specify paths like this `/Rod1/thermalMap.exe` wherever I need.

I know, How to find in `servlet` using the following code

```
   getServletContext().getRealPath("");
```

My webApps folder in the following way.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use sth like this: 

    "classpath*:whateveryouarelookingfor"

Comment: can you tell me clearly..

Comment: sorry this if you want to look for some specific context in spring or jpa annotations. i hope apologize me.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the absolute path to to your `webApp/WEB-INF/classes` directory as below:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/");
String path = resource.getPath();
```

This will return you an absolute path like this:

```
/C:/SERVERS/x/y/x/yourApp/WEB-INF/classes
```

And from this you can get the path to the `yourApp` directory:

```
path = path.replace("WEB-INF/classes/", "");
```

which you can use to specify paths like `/Rod1/thermalMap.exe`, by appending to this `path`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this?

```
 String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: I tried this.But I am getting the `Eclipse` directory.I want to find `contextPath` of my webApplication.

Comment: sth like this? http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-the-location-of-my-web-application-context-in-the-file-system.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a

```
javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
```

in your web.xml like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.my.Servlet</listener-class>
</listener>
```

From that, you can get the ServletContext on which you can call getContextPath().

Comment: I added <listener> tag element in `web.xml` file. Anyhow I am implementing `servletContextListener` inteface in my normal java class. So after adding `<listener>` element, what I have to do.can you explain clearly.

Comment: Well your class will get an instance of the ServletContextEvent in the contextInitialized() method, which provides the ServletContext. Then just use getContextPath().
If you need the value later on, just save the ServletContext as a member of your class.